# Trouble Registering Function With Spark-SQL using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm getting an error when I try to register a function with Spark - SQL that I created with the Python API.

First, I train my logistic regression model:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LinearRegressionWithSGD
LRM = LinearRegressionWithSGD()
linear_model = LRM.train(transformed_data_scaled, intercept = True)
```

I know the linear model is trained successfully because I get the following:

```
print 'Model Coefficients:', linear_model.weights
print 'Model Intercept:', linear_model.intercept

Model Coefficients: [-82.6194271643,2381.06882039,-65.0826814456,1.70454845719,-75.5970986012,-67.5109145931]
Model Intercept: 2081.56222548
```

Next, I create a function by using the following code:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors 

def predict(a,b,c,d,e,f):
  return linear_model.predict(Vectors.dense([a,b,c,d,e,f]))
```

I know this function is working correctly because I can test it as follows:

```
> predict(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Out[44]: 5789.599608026406
```

Lastly, I register the function I created with Spark-SQL as follows:

```
> sqlContext.registerFunction("predict", predict)
```

When I try to use this command in SQL, I get the following error:

```
%sql select predict(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

> Error in SQL statement: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 22181.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 22181.0 (TID 536610, ip-10-0-162-160.ec2.internal): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for
>   construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  When you call the registerFunction, you have to provide the third argument, which is the datatype.

registerFunction(name, f, returnType=StringType)

Note how the third parameter is the datatype with a default of string.  I neglected to pass this parameter so I was getting the error.

Comment: Do you know if this is possible with Pyspark functions as well? I've got a python function that returns a column expression and would like to also use it in an sql query rather than having to jump between the two syntaxes